# Joomla article overlaps in each other when going to add new article

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

Whenever i going to add new article in joomla dashboard, it gets overlapped. I used following code to display articles.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
     <div class="row">

         <jdoc:include type="component"/>

     </div>
</div>
```

I got articles in overlaps in each other. Instead i need to display articles in grid view. Can any one help me to resolve this problem.
When I inspect html element from browser I got following code snippet in row class div.

```
<div class="blog" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
    <div class="items-row cols-4 row-0 row-fluid clearfix">
        <div class="span3 col-md-3">
            <div class="item column-1" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <div class="pull-left item-image">
                    <a href="/textile/index.php/4-belt-fasteners"><img src="/textile/images/belt-fasteners.png" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"></a>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Belt Fasteners</h3>
                    <p><span class="A32"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">We stock a vast range of belt fasteners for all thickness of belts and for a variety of applications.</span></span></p>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif';">Widths: 25mm, 38.5mm, 40mm, 50mm, 57mm, 63mm, 75mm, 89mm, 100mm, 150mm, 300mm.</span></p>

                    <p class="readmore">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/textile/index.php/4-belt-fasteners" itemprop="url">
                            <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                            Read more ...   </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- end item -->
            </div><!-- end span -->
            <div class="span3 col-md-3">
                <div class="item column-2" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <div class="pull-left item-image">
                        <a href="/textile/index.php/6-belt-fasteners-3"><img src="/textile/images/belt-fasteners.png" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"></a>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Belt Fasteners</h3>
                        <p><span class="A32"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">We stock a vast range of belt fasteners for all thickness of belts and for a variety of applications.</span></span></p>
                        <p><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif';">Widths: 25mm, 38.5mm, 40mm, 50mm, 57mm, 63mm, 75mm, 89mm, 100mm, 150mm, 300mm.</span></p>
                        <p class="readmore">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="/textile/index.php/6-belt-fasteners-3" itemprop="url">
                                <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                                Read more ...   </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end item -->
                </div><!-- end span -->
                <div class="span3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="item column-3" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                        <div class="pull-left item-image">
                            <a href="/textile/index.php/8-belt-fasteners-5"><img src="/textile/images/belt-fasteners.png" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"></a>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Belt Fasteners</h3>
                            <p><span class="A32"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">We stock a vast range of belt fasteners for all thickness of belts and for a variety of applications.</span></span></p>
                            <p><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif';">Widths: 25mm, 38.5mm, 40mm, 50mm, 57mm, 63mm, 75mm, 89mm, 100mm, 150mm, 300mm.</span></p>

                            <p class="readmore">
                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="/textile/index.php/8-belt-fasteners-5" itemprop="url">
                                    <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                                    Read more ...   </a>
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end item -->
                    </div><!-- end span -->
                    <div class="span3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="item column-4" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                            <div class="pull-left item-image">
                                <a href="/textile/index.php/9-belt-fasteners-6"><img src="/textile/images/belt-fasteners.png" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"></a>

                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Belt Fasteners</h3>
                                <p><span class="A32"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">We stock a vast range of belt fasteners for all thickness of belts and for a variety of applications.</span></span></p>
                                <p><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif';">Widths: 25mm, 38.5mm, 40mm, 50mm, 57mm, 63mm, 75mm, 89mm, 100mm, 150mm, 300mm.</span></p>

                                <p class="readmore">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/textile/index.php/9-belt-fasteners-6" itemprop="url">
                                        <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                                        Read more ...   </a>
                                </p>

                            </div>
                            <!-- end item -->
                        </div><!-- end span -->
                    </div><!-- end row -->
                    <div class="items-row cols-4 row-1 row-fluid clearfix">
                        <div class="span3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="item column-1" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                                <div class="pull-left item-image">
                                    <a href="/textile/index.php/5-belt-fasteners-2"><img src="/textile/images/belt-fasteners.png" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"></a>

                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Belt Fasteners</h3>
                                    <p><span class="A32"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">We stock a vast range of belt fasteners for all thickness of belts and for a variety of applications.</span></span></p>
                                    <p><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif';">Widths: 25mm, 38.5mm, 40mm, 50mm, 57mm, 63mm, 75mm, 89mm, 100mm, 150mm, 300mm.</span></p>

                                    <p class="readmore">
                                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/textile/index.php/5-belt-fasteners-2" itemprop="url">
                                            <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                                            Read more ...   </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <!-- end item -->
                            </div><!-- end span -->
                            <div class="span3 col-md-3">
                                <div class="item column-2" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                                    <div class="pull-left item-image">
                                        <a href="/textile/index.php/7-belt-fasteners-4"><img src="/textile/images/belt-fasteners.png" alt="" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Belt Fasteners</h3>
                                        <p><span class="A32"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">We stock a vast range of belt fasteners for all thickness of belts and for a variety of applications.</span></span></p>
                                        <p><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif';">Widths: 25mm, 38.5mm, 40mm, 50mm, 57mm, 63mm, 75mm, 89mm, 100mm, 150mm, 300mm.</span></p>
                                        <p class="readmore">
                                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="/textile/index.php/7-belt-fasteners-4" itemprop="url">
                                                <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                                                Read more ...   </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end item -->
                                </div><!-- end span -->
                            </div><!-- end row -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is very poorly formated, and is unreadable as is.

Comment: Highly possible that tags in the article are incomplete. Browsers usually try to make them complete and add tags by themselves resulting in faulty tags. Instead of "inspect html element", try "View Source" and check the tags. If you try this in Mozilla, you will get a red color for incomplete tags! Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Add clearfix class to your parent div

like so

```
<div class="col-md-9 clearfix">
     <div class="row clearfix">

         <jdoc:include type="component"/>

     </div>
</div>
```

or

```
style="clear:both"
```